# Space created in header

Tags: php, html

When I look my source code, I have a space create at the top of the page
Do you have an idea why I have that?

When i generate a xml I have this. My xml is correct.

```
This page contains the following errors:

error on line 2 at column 6: XML declaration allowed only at the start of the document
Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.
```

Tk

my code is like this (without whitespace)

```
<?php
/**
* header.php
*/
use \OM\HTML;
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

when  I look the source code I have this.

`<br>` is included to show you the problem, but in reality, there is nothing.

```
<br>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html dir="ltr" lang="fr">
<head>
```

Comment: And what is there in real? Blank line before `<!doctype>` has no function, it's not problem.

Answer (score 0):

Because you have a return between `?>` and `<!DOCTYPE html>`

make it `?><!DOCTYPE html>` to fix